# The mode about geometric distribution.

Tags: probability-theory

A random variable, X, is defined as X ~ Geo(p). I know the mode is 1 as it is the value of X with highest probability.

How do i show this? As this is a discrete R.V, can i be allowed to use Calculus? I can proceed if i knew that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The probability distribution, as you've set it out, is

$$
P(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p \qquad k \in \mathbb{N}
$$

It should then be simple to show that for any integer $k > 1$,

\begin{align}
P(X = 1) & = p \\
         & > (1-p)^{k-1}p \\
         & = P(X = k)
\end{align}

provided $0 < p < 1$, so that $0 < 1-p < 1$ and $0 < (1-p)^{k-1} < 1$.